# SciPy - 'Object too deep for desired array' when subclassing rv_continuous

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability

I'm trying to generate a 2D uniform distribution by subclassing [`rv_continuous`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous).

```
from scipy import stats
class uniform_2d(stats.rv_continuous):   
    def _pdf(self, x, y):
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        result = 1/(max(x)*max(y)) * np.ones_like(X)
        return result

x = y = np.linspace(1,3,3)
uni = uniform_2d(name="uni")
pdf = uni.pdf(x,y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolor(X,Y,pdf)
```

It fails when trying to return my result, giving the following error:

`ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

What's happening? My result has shape (3, 3) and has class `numpy.ndarray` - why can't I simply return one `numpy.ndarray`?

EDIT: Also, am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a simpler way to make a 2D uniform distribution using `scipy.stats`?

Answer (score 3):

`rv_continuous` is for univariate distributions only. You can look at [`scipy/stats/_multivariate.py`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a22f0748ef9d7e0a63f0b4ca4e673b97c07e57fc/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py) for how we are making multivariate distribution objects. At the moment, there is no common base class, just an expected interface.

Comment: Well, for my purposes, I got a workaround by simply using a multivariate_norm distribution instead. I'm kind of surprised that multivariate distributions are so underdeveloped in SciPi!